# Using Selenium Commands on HTML content stored in a local varialble

Tags: selenium-webdriver

This may sound odd BUT Is it possible to use WebDriver commands on a static variable that holds the html source? (eg: findElementbyId)

This is what i want to do:

1. set firefox webDriver
2. open website url
3. save the HTML pageSource to a "static local variable"
4. quit webDriver
5. Now - i want to be able to findElements and texts within this locally stored PageSource. (preferably using the selenium commands)

Any help and/or suggestion is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically **no**, it falls down at (5). The FirefoxDriver needs to communicate with an actual Firefox browser using the [WebDriver protocol](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/). Selenium can't work with just a String.

It's not clear what your use case is, but you could do things like copy the HTML to a temporary file, generate a `file:` URL for it, load it with the HtmlUnit or PhantomJS drivers and re-run your tests in-memory.

Surely plain old regular expressions, or an HTML parser like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/), are better options for post-processing HTML?